# get (dynamic loading page) contents using PHP/CURL?

Tags: php, curl, web, boot

I try to program a webboot using PHP/CURL, but I face a problem in handling a specific page that it's loading some contents dynamically !! .. **to explain more** :
when I try to download the page using PHP/CURL, I do not get some contents ! then I discovered that this contents are loaded after page is loaded. and this is why CURL does not handle these missed contents.

can any one help me !

my sample code is :

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $reffer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $redirect);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, ABSOLUTE_PATH."Cookies/cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, ABSOLUTE_PATH."Cookies/cookies.txt");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: no matter what you do curl won't act as a browser with javascript enabled, so you can't get content fetched via ajax/jsonp etc; you can try a testing platform that simulates a browser, but it seems to defeat the purpose; not even google parses this type of content; if you just need data from that page (and you are not creating a crawler) just make multiple calls and replicate the system

Comment: 'just make multiple calls and replicate the system' .. can you explain! .. and can you name one of these 'platform that simulates a browser' . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What URL are you trying to load? It could be that the page you're requesting has one or more AJAX requests that load content in after the fact. I don't think that cURL can accomodate runtime-loaded information via AJAX or other XHR request.

You might want to look at something like [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/), which is a headless WebKit browser which will execute the page fully and return the dynamically assembled DOM.

Comment: shorouknews.com/caricature/waleed

Comment: Yes, it's definitely loading data after the page loads via AJAX

Comment: Thanks, and I did it with [json post](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/posting-json-data-with-php-curl) with curl

Answer (score 0):

Because the page uses javascript to load the content, you are not going to be able to do this via cURL. Check out this page for more information on the problem: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/11/spiders-view-of-web-20.html