# PHP Crawler dynamic loaded content

Tags: php, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl the leaderboard table from [this url](http://www.pokerstars.eu/poker/tournaments/micro-millions/player-of-the-series/), but it is loaded dynamically after a few milliseconds, so I can't access it from the dom. I am using this code so far:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile("http://www.pokerstars.eu/poker/tournaments/micro-millions/player-of-the-series/");
$el = $dom->getElementById('siteHeader');
```

Where siteHeader is loaded in the dom, however, the div I want to access is not there straight away. Its added after a second or so.

Is there any way to put in some kind of sleep, so I have this code in my DOM?

Comment: possible duplicate of [get (dynamic loading page) contents using PHP/CURL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687383/get-dynamic-loading-page-contents-using-php-curl)

Comment: The thing is that I really want it to be with PHP, as I have to do one simple action with it (obviously I can make AJAX requests, but it would suck to have so many code for just this simple action I want to do). Are there any other possible solutions? If not, then I will have to use this. Thanks for the share :-)

Comment: I know this is an old link but only the first thing I found. I think you need to do more research, if this is even possible